# Javascript Android chrome listen to select on change event

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, dom

I am trying to listen to the select change event. So every time, when an user clicks on an option in a select input, I want to fire some functionality. All is fine, except Android does not work.

My code is as follows

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {console.log(123);} );
```

This works on desktop, ios, but not Android's Chrome (API 28), vanilla build, on Android emulator (Not an emulation issue, this doesn't work on real phones also).

Screenshot to illustrate

[image]

Going into detail, I found out that the change event is fired, when the OK button is clicked on the bottom right. I want it to fire instantly on clicking an option.

I also tried

```
$('option').on('click'...
$('#select').on('click'...
$('#select option').on('click'...
$('#select option').on('change'...
```

etc..

## Edit 1

It was requested that I also post the DOM.

```
<select id="select">
    <option>All</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: share all relevant code in the OP

Comment: What do you mean? The only relevant code is how to get any function to run when clicking an option, which is all there.

Comment: i dont see the option.

Comment: Check Edit 1 . .